# Using the mod operator to decrease value in a textbox

Tags: c#, modulo

Okay so I have created this vending machine application form and I am having problems getting rid of the change. The machine has 50 10p's in at the start of the day. A fizzy drink costs 40p, so, if the user puts in 50p, he will get change back of 10p. I have a textbox showing the amount of 10p's in the machine, so at the start, 50, after he puts in 50p it will be 55. However, now that he has to get 10p change (I have a release change button), I want the amount of 10p's in the textbox to go to 54...any ideas? I tried using the mod operator but wasn't sure how to use it:

```
        decimal change = decimal.Parse(txtChange.Text)

        if (change % 10 > 1)
        {
            int tenPenny = int.Parse(txt_BoxTenPenny.Text);
            int totalTenPen = tenPenny - 1;
            txt_BoxTenPenny.Text = totalTenPen.ToString();
        }
```

I know this isn't right, when I was doing research, they were using the % operator and using the number 10 as the numerator..so..I got a bit lost. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: If he puts in 50p, how does the number of 10ps increase by 5? Are you saying the user puts in 50p in 10s? If so, the change is irrelevant as you can reject excess, and, therefore, so is the assignment.

Comment: If they put 50p in you don't have 55 you still have 50.

Comment: That is the integer division remainder operator. So x % 10 gives the last digit of x if x is non negative integer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
    decimal change = decimal.Parse(txtChange.Text)

    if (change % 10 > 0)
    {
        int tenPenny = int.Parse(txt_BoxTenPenny.Text);
        int totalTenPen = tenPenny - (change % 10);
        txt_BoxTenPenny.Text = totalTenPen.ToString();
    }
```

But is supposed that before that, you have added the 50p the users puts into machine in the `txt_BoxTenPenny`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to determine how many 10 pennies the user is owed, this is calculated using:

```
int tenPennies = change / 10
```

As opposed to the modulus (%) operator, so:

```
    decimal change = decimal.Parse(txtChange.Text)

    int tenPenny = int.Parse(txt_BoxTenPenny.Text);
    int totalTenPen = tenPenny - change / 10 ;
    txt_BoxTenPenny.Text = totalTenPen.ToString();
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator (`%`) returns the *remainder* of a division operation. For example, `23 MOD 10 = 3`.

In this case I believe you want integer division, or the `Floor`. That is, you want to divide and throw away the remainder.

Since you are using `decimal`, I presume `change` will contain `0.10` for 10p. In that case, try the following:

```
//calculate the number of 10p coins you will get for change
var tenPenniesChange = (int)Math.Floor(change / 0.10m);

if(tenPenniesChange > 0)
    txt_BoxTenPenny.Text = (int.Parse(txt_BoxTenPenny.Text) - tenPenniesChange).ToString();

change -= tenPenniesChange * 0.10;
```

Note the use of the `Math.Floor` function. If you had `change = 0.13` you will get `tenPenniesChange = 1`. After the subtraction, you will then get `change = 0.03`.

Answer (score -1):

This may be of some use: 
[Issuing vending machine change: Using C# to recursively build and search a tree](http://patrickjarfish.com/blog/?p=13)